# Moving object between two path points unity 2D C#

Tags: unityscript

How to move object between two path points?
I need the simplest code which I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

this keyword is Patrol. You must set two or more points then repeating object points way.

[Check this article](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-AgentPatrol.html)

[video sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yBcgg4h-bc)